# Hybrid vs Html 5 vs Native

Tags: html, cross-platform, native, hybrid-mobile-app

Hello Android developers today I want to ask that which is the best html5 ,native, hybrid. Well I like html5 because of its cross platform and write once use anywhere system. I like native because it is flexible and powerful. So please guide me in the following situations

situation 1: A beautiful health app to remind you about your fitness schedule

situation 2 : A beautiful app for remainders which can sync with your computer or any other device

situation 3 : A advertisement app for buisness

situation 4 : An app for sos messages and women safety

Well I am a moderate developer .And also suggest me frame work to use or libtary for android

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating between native and html 5/hybrid is very application specific. As pointed out by yourself it is dependant on the complexity of the application.

**Native**: Applications which are more graphics oriented like games. Using accelerometer also is better done using native apps. The disadvantage is that you would need to develop it multiple times across all the mobile OSs.

**Hybrid/HTML5**: Applications which have pretty straight forward functionality more like a form based app. Example apps would be business apps developed for enterprises. Disadvantage would be slightly slower performance and graphics support.

Regarding your situation:

**Situation 1** : Native. You would mostly want to use the Accelerometer, Geolocation and provide a application which uses the maximum power of the graphics to provide a fluid and beautiful UI.

**Situation 2 & 3** : Hybrid. As you need the application to work across mobile devices and desktop devices. You can look at hybrid framework providers like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) & [Mowbly](http://mowbly.com).